# Condition Formatting not Working in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, formatting, formula, spreadsheet

I have written a formula:

```
=IF(len(d2)>0,IF(d2=0,true,false),IF(len(e2)>0,IF(e2=0,true,false),false))
```

I want to strike through entire row if the formula returns true. But it is not working. Annoying facts are:

1. If I place this formula into a cell, it shows correct true or false value.
2. If I apply this formula on entire row, only A2 and B2 cells are formatted.
3. To test whether there is come conflict with other formatting rules, I just removed the formula, and just wrote "true" in the custom formula column. And the entire row was formatted. I pasted formula into a cell and it was also returning true. How does the fomula which is returning true in the cell is returning false in conditional formatting?
4. I applied the formula to cells which have no other conditional formatting rules. The formula didn't work. So how the formula was working for A2 and B2 cells?
5. I tried using values other than true/false. As usually, it worked perfectly in cell, but not in conditional formatting.
6. It is not working even on fresh spreadsheet.

Please check it yourself. To get "True" value from the formula, enter 0 in d2 and e2 and see yourself that conditional formatting is not respecting it.

Thanks in advance for giving time to read the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the formula is only working for cells `A2` and `B2` is because `D2` and `E2` in the formula are *relative* references, which means that these cells in the formula shift as the cell which is applying the conditional formatting also shifts.

In other words, cell `A2` considers this as the formula:

```
=IF(LEN(D2)>0,IF(D2=0,TRUE,FALSE),IF(LEN(E2)>0,IF(E2=0,TRUE,FALSE),FALSE))
```

And cell `B2` considers this as the formula:

```
=IF(LEN(E2)>0,IF(E2=0,TRUE,FALSE),IF(LEN(F2)>0,IF(F2=0,TRUE,FALSE),FALSE))
```

Notice how the formula had the cells shift over.

The problem occurs when it gets to cell `C2`, which considers the formula as this:

```
=IF(LEN(F2)>0,IF(F2=0,TRUE,FALSE),IF(LEN(G2)>0,IF(G2=0,TRUE,FALSE),FALSE))
```

Presumably neither `F2` nor `G2` contains the data you're looking for, which is why the conditional formatting rule is not applied.

To fix this, you can change the formula to an *absolute* reference so that it always refers to the `D` and `E` columns, like so:

```
=IF(LEN($D2)>0,IF($D2=0,TRUE,FALSE),IF(LEN($E2)>0,IF($E2=0,TRUE,FALSE),FALSE))
```

This way, all cells in the 2nd row will consider *precisely* the above formula when checking the formatting (i.e. the cells will not shift).

---

On a side note, parts of your formula are redundant.

```
= IF(<condition>,TRUE,FALSE)
```

is equivalent to just

```
= <condition>
```

And additionally, if a third argument in an `IF` statement is not specified, `FALSE` is the default.

That being said, this formula can be simplified to:

```
=IF(LEN($D2)>0,$D2=0,IF(LEN($E2)>0,$E2=0))
```

Comment: You are genius.

Comment: @KunalKhanna Not really genius, I just have a bunch of experience with conditional formatting in excel.